# I want to do sum and Power to a list using a function with C

Tags: c

I'm new to c I want to do sum and Power to a list using a function with C but i'm having a problem in argument list(named t[]) in the function also i want to print the results any solution

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int SomProd(int t[20],int n);
int main()
{
    int i,n,t[20],s,p;
    printf("donner taille du tab");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("t[i]= ");
        scanf("%d",&t[i]);

    }
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        s=SomProd(t[i],n);
        p=SomProd(t[i],n);
        printf(" %d",s);
        printf(" %d",p);

    }

    return 0;
}
int SomProd(int t[20],int n)
{
    int i,s,p;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        s+=t[i];
        p*=t[i];
    }
    return(s,p);
}
```

Comment: Tip: Don't forget to initialize your variables. `s` and `p` are just random junk here.

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: Also `return(s,p)` does not do what you think it does. The return type is `int` as in *one integer* and one integer *only*.

Comment: Array indexes go from `0` to `N - 1`

Comment: Unrelated, stop fighting zero-based indexing in C.

Comment: You make two calls to the same function to get `s` and `p`. The simple answer is to have two functions, one for sum, one for product. Remember that the product can overflow very quickly.

Comment: Also you should not pass an array to a function with `s = SomProd(t[i], n);`, but as `s = SomProd(t, n);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this (untested code):

```
int Somme(int t[20], int n);
int Produit(int t[20], int n);

int main()
{
    int i, n ,t[20], s, p;

    printf("Donnez taille du tableau");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("t[%d]= ", i);
        scanf("%d", &t[i]);    
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        s = Somme(t, n);
        p = Produit(t, n);
        printf("Somme = %d", s);
        printf("Produit = %d", p);
    }

    return 0;
}

int Somme(int t[20], int n)
{
    int i, somme = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        somme += t[i];
    }

    return somme;
}

int Produit(int t[20], int n)
{
    int i, prod = 1;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        prod *= t[i];
    }

    return prod;
}
```

There is still room for further improvement.

Comment: Thank you that was helpfull !!